# Cancel AsyncTasks from collection

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Let's say I have TasksManager which has static List tasks (not sure list is good solution) and there are static methods `addTaskToList(MyTask task){tasks.add(task);}, 
removeTaskFromList(MyTask task){tasks.remove(task);}`
Each task in doInBackground() calls first method, and in onPostExecute() there is second method call with "this".
MyTask has String field "method".

I want to cancel tasks of this list where task.getMethod().contains("url")..
not sure this code is good enough for stable working.. looks like onCancelled() of task not always called, multitreading can be dangerous for such methods I think.

```
   for (MyTask task : tasks) {
        if (task.getMethod().contains("url")) {
            task.cancel(true);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Is it normal practice to store tasks in this way or you can suggest me more elegant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cancelling an `AsyncTask` isn't always an immediate/obvious thing. If you are using `cancel`, you also need to make sure `doInBackground` is aware of [`isCancelled`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and you have to stop what you were doing yourself (see the docs for `isCancelled`).

I wouldn't recommended storing a list of `AsyncTask` objects and iterating them for doing sequential background work anyway. That sounds like it might get very messy very quickly. Each `AsyncTask` creates a new `Thread`, and that doesn't sound like what you want. Rather, you may just want one background thread you can do stuff on?

For one background thread you can use a [HandlerThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#q=HandlerThread) and your own Looper, as follows:

```
HandlerThread backThread = new HandlerThread("BackLooper", Thread.NORM_PRIORITY);
backThread.start();
Looper backLooper = backThread.getLooper();

private synchronized void runOnBackThread(Runnable r) {
   new Handler(backLooper).post(r);
}
```

Then each item you want to run in sequence you can post on the back thread by submitting a `Runnable`. And, you can also use the other [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) post variants too, postDelayed, postAt, and so on.

And, depending on what you're doing you may find [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) *very* helpful. `IntentService` is provided specifically for a "work queue" type pattern. It has one background thread, does whatever you tell it to do ONE AT A TIME when you invoke it, and goes away on its own when it's not needed.

Lastly, if you're looking for a really nice general "task" type library for Android check out Square's [Tape](http://square.github.com/tape/). That's not directly related to your question, but I find Tape super handy for more robust "queue it up" task type situations.

Comment: I know that cancel isn't immediate thing, my main objective is not returning final result from task. One background thread is a bad idea, sometimes there is up to 20 simultaineous asynctasks with different "method" fields.

Comment: So I don't see any other variants except of storing and iterating them, but it is really messy and not working..

Comment: "One background thread is a bad idea,", hah, ok, but you're gonna have a bad time.

Comment: Did you bother reading the part about isCancelled? If you want to use a bunch of AsyncTasks, and cancel them based on a string comparison (another issue with this, but I digress), make sure you understand what "cancel" does. Hint: it doesn't really cancel, it waves a flag saying "hey, this SHOULD be canceled" so *you* can stop whatever it is you need to stop in doInBackground.

Comment: I understand this, ok. I'll try to find another way to do what I want. Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to cancel the tasks, if you want to stick with that route, but you just have to check for isCancelled inside doInBackground and bail out yourself. That way calling "cancel" will actually work.